# How to get Capybara matchers to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm searching for a CSS class. My HAML is:

```
.friends
    = image_tag 'news-face.png'
    %p 15
```

My test is:

```
it "Should show friends count on popular feed" do
  visit '/'
  page.should have_css('.friends')
end
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_css('.friends')
   expected css ".friends" to return something
```

I've tried `should`, `should_not`, & `have_selector` and can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you don't have such element on your page. The best way to figure it out by yourself is to install:

```
# in your Gemfile
gem 'launchy'
```

and then just use:

```
# in Cucumber step
it "Should show friends count on popular feed" do
  visit '/'
  save_and_open_page
  page.should have_css('.friends')
end
```

With this gem and command you will be able to render this page from your test.

Comment: Whoa thats cool! I tried this and it came back with a incredibly 'unrendered' page.  Just a taste:  http://d.pr/LXI8  , any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Comment: I should add that, I can see that the html selector I'm trying to find isn't there when viewing the html from save_and_open_page in my tmp folder.. even though it is when I view the page in my browser.. I don't know why that would be..

Comment: Wow, now I feel silly.. your post helped me realize that what was 'missing' was actually rendered collections, because I didn't have any items in my testing database :-| But your answer taught me a lot so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would use `has_css` selector.